# Google Maps Autocomplete - Clear input if nothing selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm using Google maps autocomplete script and its working fine, but how to clear input if user has not select anyone from a dropdown list?

For example: 
Current situation:
User enter "New" and see "New york" in a list, but do not choose it (clicks anywhere outside the input), and now intup has value "New".
I want:
User enter "New" and see "New york" in a list, but do not choose it (clicks anywhere outside the input), and now intup has empty value, because nothing in the list is not selected.

My current code:

```
   <input id="autocomplete2" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="initAutocomplete2()" type="text">
<script>
    function initAutocomplete2() {
      autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
          /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete2')),
          {types: ['(cities)']});

   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will need to have a variable to save the fact that a value was selected, and then when someone focus/blur the input - reset the value of the input if needed.

Here is an example:

```js
var selected = false;

function initAutocomplete2() {
  autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete2')),
    {types: ['(cities)']});
  
  autocomplete2.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    selected = true
  });
}
$('#autocomplete2').on('focus', function() {
  selected = false;
  }).on('blur', function() {
    if (!selected) {
      $(this).val('');
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<input id="autocomplete2" placeholder="Enter your address" onFocus="initAutocomplete2()" type="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way that seems better to me, you can define an "old value" that changes only by "place_changed" callback.
Then, on "blur" event you should refill the value with last picked one (or the initial value).
This way the field  value is consistent, it's empty or a valid picked value.

```
var oldaddress = $("input[name='address']").val();

$("input[name='address']").on('blur', function () {
  $(this).val(oldaddress);
});

function initAutocomplete() {
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    document.getElementById('address'),
    {types: [(cities)]}
  );
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
// ....
  oldaddress = $("input[name='address']").val();
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me, the blur event triggers before the place_changed event, both when clicking to select and when using arrows + enter to select.